# What exactly does builder.Services.AddControllers() do?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When I create a new ASP.NET Core 6/7 WebApi project and check the option "Use Controllers...." in VS 2022, this line appears in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

The scaffolded `WeatherForecastController` is working properly. However in case I comment this line

```
// builder.Services.AddControllers();
```

still everything is working fine.

**Question**: what exactly does `builder.Services.AddControllers()` do?

Comment: You can always use the source. Start at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bec278eabea54f63da15e10e654bdfa4168a2479/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L79

Comment: Short answer: adds services and routing logic so controllers/actions can handle requests. This includes things like action filters. For the simplest use cases most of the extras are not needed, and thus you don't need those helpers.

Comment: many thanks, sounds like an answer

Answer (score 0):

The [`AddController`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcservicecollectionextensions.addcontrollers?view=aspnetcore-7.0) method(actually it is `MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllers`) registers everything that is needed for Web API Development. The services include Support for Controllers, Model Binding, API Explorer, Authorization, CORS, Validations, Formatter Mapping, etc.

For example, what if I want to tweak security of my API by changing CORS settings? After I change these settings, the middleware must register, that is to reflect my intention, them. Apropos the changes, it also shows importance of order of registrations.

Answer (score -2):

ASP.Net Core has an inbuilt dependency injection framework. So, that means we do not need containers like the UnityContainer to inject the dependencies into our application.

Now for an Mvc Application there will be a lot of classes that needs to be injected to have the Mvc application working. These classes are all categorised and bundled inside their own extensions methods of IServiceCollection. In the code above the following are the extensions method that bundles the services to be injected for their functionality.

- AddMvcCore()
- AddApiExplorer()
- AddAuthorization()
- AddCors()
- AddDataAnnotations()
- AddFormatterMappings()

All these methods are chained and invoked inside the parent wrapper extension method that is AddControllersCore() which is called from the AddControllers() method.

Answer (score -3):

**builder.Services.AddControllers()** configures services related to controllers like processing HTTP requests, model binding, validations, content negotiation, etc. It also registers necessary dependencies for routing and handling HTTP requests.